# html5 detect how many files being dropped?

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

Is it possible to detect how many files are being dropped using HTML5 drag/drop? I can detect the number of files using e.dataTransfer.files once the files have been dropped but the filesList is empty for ondragover & ondragenter events.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this :

> e.dataTransfer.files.length

Comment: yep.. I can use that when the file has been dropped, but can I get the length before the file has been dropped? and is currently being dragged?

Comment: You can not get the data or length of dragging file. Perhaps this is a security problems.